# Auto hot key AHK script for this logic to save wallpapers from website

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, save-as

I am sure auto hot key handles this but not sure how to do it. Here is the scenario. I have 10 tabs open on Google chrome. In each chrome tab, there is a wallpaper photo that I need to save. This is what I want when I press A&H together.

1. The cursor should go to 0,0 coordinates
2. Then cursor right clicks on coordinates in the exact 960, 500
3. Then cursor moves to the 2nd menu item from the context menu, and it clicks on "Save Image As.."
4. Then just hit enter to save the image.
5. 3 seconds delay - as chrome saving the image.
6. Then close current window by pressing Ctrl+W  (this is shortcut key for chrome tab close)
7. half second delay
8. Repeat Step 1.   (I want to run this script for like 24 times )

I want slight delays in cursor speed so that my eye can notice what is going on.

Can anyone help in writing a AHK script for me, please? I want this script to be run on wallhaven.cc wallpapers site.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Try the [Mouse And Keyboard Macro Recorder](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=34184#p158285).

Comment: Thank you so much, with the help of this I able to create the script I exactly wanted. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
; Tested Auto hot key script:

; This script triggers when I click side mouse button 2. 

Xbutton2::
Loop, 5
{
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

    Sleep, 1000
    MouseMove, 0, 0, 70
    MouseClick, L, 0, 0
    Sleep, 1000

    MouseMove, 1013, 356, 100
    MouseClick, R, 1013, 356

    MouseMove, 1055, 399, 30
    MouseClick, L, 1055, 399

    Sleep, 1000

    Send, {Enter}

    ; saving image time 2 seconds
    Sleep, 2000

    ; closing the current chorme tab, so that the 2nd tab auto shift to left side
    Send, ^w
    Sleep, 500

    If (A_Index = 5)
       return
}
```

Note this script only works for the scenario mentioned in the question.